# Using Double Query Strings to Send Mail in Address Bar

Tags: javascript, query-string

I have a very simple Node.js Video Chat that I am using to call my friends. I want it to interface directly with Mail (open up Mail with a template loaded). I have this so far:

```js
let obsPass = /* helpers.generateObsPassword() < randomly generated char */ 'zH1mA4pR2hF7wJ5'
var text = location.href + '&obs=' + obsPass;
window.open(`mailto:?subject=Join%20meeting&body=${text}`);
```

It works! The body for this Mail should be `https://example.com?room=myroom&obs=zH1mA4pR2hF7wJ5`, however, when I use this to open mail, the body doesn't say `https://example.com?room=myroom&obs=zH1mA4pR2hF7wJ5`, it says `https://example.com?room=myroom`. I think it has to do with the double query strings that I have (mailto:? and example.com?) which is causing the browser to think that the `&obs=zH1mA4pR2hF7wJ5` is being applied to the bigger "website", `mailto:`.

Is there a fix for this? I could manually send the email, but I am hoping to integrate this into my site. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the URL in the message body.

Instead of writing

```js
window.open(`mailto:?subject=Join%20meeting&body=${text}`);
```

write

```js
window.open(`mailto:?subject=Join%20meeting&body=${encodeURIComponent(text)}`);
```

Without this, your `mailto:` URL would end up as

```
mailto:?subject=Join%20meeting&body=https://example.com?room=myroom&obs=zH1mA4pR2hF7wJ5
```

In a URL query-string, `&` denotes the end of one parameter value and the start of the next parameter.  Hence, this `mailto:` URL has three parameters in the query string, `subject`, `body` and `obs`, and the value of the `body` parameter is `https://example.com?room=myroom`.

If you want the `&` character after `myroom` to be part of the value of `body`, then you need to encode it.  Encoding it prevents the URL parser in your mail program from interpreting it as the end of one of the parameters in the `mailto:` URL.  Your mail program should then decode the value it pulls out of the `body` parameter in your `mailto:` URL before putting it in the message body of the email.

Comment: Amazing answer!